# Can't enable Shell_exec ( )

Tags: php, shell-exec

I have this error:

> `shell_exec()` has been disabled for security reasons

At disable functions I have this :

```
disable_functions = pcntl_alarm,pcntl_fork,pcntl_waitpid,pcntl_wait,pcntl_wifexited,pcntl_wifstopped,pcntl_wifsignaled,pcntl_wexitstatus,pcntl_wtermsig,pcntl_wstopsig,pcntl_signal,pcntl_signal_dispatch,pcntl_get_last_error,pcntl_strerror,pcntl_sigprocmask,pcntl_sigwaitinfo,pcntl_sigtimedwait,pcntl_exec,pcntl_getpriority,pcntl_setpriority
```

And also: `safe_mode = Off`

But still it says is disabled..what can I do ?

Comment: if you are using some cheap shared hosting service, sometime they wont allow  you to use these functions for securtiy purposes

Comment: I own a vps...do you think still that this is the problem ?

Comment: Did you restart your web server (apache/nginx) or php handler?

Comment: Yes, all those info where taken from phpinfo();

Comment: If you have installed suhosin extension, check suhosin.executor.func.blacklist

Comment: The suhosin extension was the problem, thank you very much !!